# TYPO3 install from dummy and source

Tags: typo3

I want to install typo3 using dummy and source packages, how is it done ? i unpack both tar.gz into each own directory or mix them into one single directory ?

Even creating ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL file and giving permissions, the instalation is is still locked.

Thank's in advance

Comment: Where did you created `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` file?

Comment: Hi i download now the source+dummy and create the ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL inside typo3conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also `source+dummy` package available, download it and unzip. Downloading separate `dummy` or `source` packs makes sense only when you want to add missing element or update the sources.

http://typo3.org/download/

Comment: i download source+dummy unpack and create the ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL in typo3conf folder , and assign permissions on the file try to hit the instalation by the browser : localhost/typo3conf/install and it shows the screen telling "Install tool is locked" even having the file in the right folder

Comment: Is that possible, that your http://localhost/ vhost points another folder than the one where you unzipped to package ? Check if you can get the file with the browser: http://localhost/typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL if not, check the vhost settings and ensure that you reloaded/restarted the Apache

Comment: Now it is installed i just need to give permissions to uploads fileadmin and typo3temp directories